MacOS desktop widgets zoomed in/cut off
I recently encountered an issue where the widgets on my Mac's Home Screen were cut off at the top. The issue would occur occasionally, even in the last OS version (I'm currently in Sequoia beta).
Here's the solution that worked for me:
Open the Terminal application. You can find it in Applications > Utilities or by searching for it using Spotlight (Cmd + Space).
Type the following command and press Enter:
killall NotificationCenter

This command restarts the Notification Center process, which appears to be responsible for managing the widgets. After running this command, the Notification Center will momentarily disappear and then reappear, refreshing the widgets and displaying them correctly.
I hope this helps anyone experiencing the same issue!

Please take the tour to see how this site works. A question should be just the question. If you wish to answer your own question you would follow it up with a separate answer. Secondly, questions regarding macOS betas are generally not accepted here, and should be reported to Apple via their beta feedback. However if you can provide evidence of the issue in Sonoma, then do so (and remove references to betas). I'd suggest you edit your question, and provide a separate answer, with these points in mind.
